# Exception with (Custom) RestAuthenticationProcessingFilter Ordering

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security

I try to add Rest authentication by token to my app. 
I created a simple filter doing nothing else print a message :

```
public class RestAuthenticationProcessingFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest arg0, ServletResponse arg1, FilterChain arg2) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println(arg0);
        // EDIT 25/02/2014
        arg2.doFilter(arg0,arg1);
    }
}
```

I'm using Spring 4.0 and Spring Security 3.2 with JavaConfig.

I added this in my adapter :

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    /*
     * @RemarqueDev Différence entre permitAll et anonymous : permitAll
     * contient anonymous. Anonymous uniquement pour non connecté
     */
     http.addFilter(new RestAuthenticationProcessingFilter());
     http.csrf().disable().headers().disable();
     http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint());
}
```

When I run jetty server, I receive this message:

```
Nested in org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.servlet.Filter org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The Filter class my.package.config.RestAuthenticationProcessingFilter does not have a registered order and cannot be added without a specified order. Consider using addFilterBefore or addFilterAfter instead.:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The Filter class com.jle.athleges.config.RestAuthenticationProcessingFilter does not have a registered order and cannot be added without a specified order. Consider using addFilterBefore or addFilterAfter instead.
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity.addFilter(HttpSecurity.java:1122)
```

Why?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`addFilter`:

> Adds a Filter that must be an instance of or extend one of the Filters
>   provided within the Security framework. The method ensures that the
>   ordering of the Filters is automatically taken care of. The ordering
>   of the Filters is:...

Your filter is not an instance or extend of the Filter within the Security framework.

What you can do however is use `addFilterBefore` or `addFilterAfter`.

For example:

```
addFilterBefore(new RestAuthenticationProcessingFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
```

You can find the order of the security filter chain in the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/HttpSecurityBuilder.html#addFilter%28javax.servlet.Filter%29).

Comment: It is working but now, when I go to login page, I receive a 404 page not found.
I added this code : 
`http.addFilterBefore(new RestAuthenticationProcessingFilter(),UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class`

And a line of code in my filter (I edit the code in my original post)
But it is working with other non-secure page
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Spring defines a sorting rule for security filters, check the constructor org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.FilterComparator.  when you call org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity# When addFilter, its method will use org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.FilterComparator built-in security filter sorting rules to check whether the Filter is registered. When it is not registered, it will throw "does not have a registered order", and it will be resolved. The method is to manually provide the registration order, call org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity#addFilterBefore or org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity#addFilterAfter to register in a built-in filter Before or after. please chcek the spring security internal filters sort "https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.2/reference/html5/#servlet-security-filters".
-- Please forgive me if I can't write well in English.