# In production, mock authentication for Spring Security - from reverse proxy; but my filter get's no @Inject

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, servlet-filters

## tl;dr

I need a Java Servet Filter to receive Injected dependencies like all my other classes are able to. (those others are called from Spring's own Servlet I guess)

Why `@Inject` has no effect - stays `null`? (**What I've tried**, below.) I am presently adding new filter in `web.xml` but traditional way does not work. But maybe need to link in with Spring filter delegator or `<bean>`?

How can I get a filter loaded as a `<bean>` so the `@Inject` lines will work?

## Full Question

#### Overview

I know little about Spring. Here's what we have

- Spring authentication
- Seems to be Spring session management

What we want is

- reverse proxy server handles authentication (I will create)
- mock a successful authentication based on HTTP headers (filter reads headers passed by reverse proxy, verifies them, and then does not require authentication, as the reverse proxy has already done it on that end)
- using something like `SecurityContextUtil.setAuthentication(auth)` would allow all existing uses of authentication to read my mocked object. This way not every page or endpoint needs to read reverse proxy headers because filter would do this

#### What we have

In `web.xml` we have

```xml
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

And we have `MySecurityConfig.java`, which as a class name is never referenced, so I assume Spring must be scanning for one of the annotations in all classes and finds this one.

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MySecurityConfig extends
WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
       @Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
       @Override
       public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
           return super.authenticationManagerBean();
       }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(
      AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
  
        auth
            .authenticationProvider(authProvider())
            .authenticationEventPublisher(eventPublisher());
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        ...
        
        http
                .csrf()
                    .ignoringAntMatchers("...")
                    .csrfTokenRepository(cookieCsrfRepo)
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/...").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/...").hasRole("...")
                    .antMatchers("/...").hasRole("...")
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/...")
                ...
                .loginProcessingUrl("/...")
                .authenticationDetailsSource(myAuthenticationDetailsSource)
                .successHandler(myAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                .failureHandler(myAuthenticationFailureHandler)
                .permitAll()       
            .and()  
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessHandler(myLogoutSuccessHandler)
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"));
    }
    
    @Bean
    public MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler myAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
        return new MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        return new MyAuthenticationProvider();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationEventPublisher eventPublisher() {
        return new DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher();
    }
}
```

#### I have noticed

Whenever a new thread is spawned, the authentication is attached to the new thread, like so:

```java
        SecurityContextUtil.setAuthentication(auth);
```

**In a certain test** we mock the authentication like this:

```java
    @Inject
    private AuthenticationManager am;

    @Before
    public void authenticateTestUser() {
        MyAuthenticationDetails details = mock(MyAuthenticationDetails.class); // Mockito
        when(details.getThing()).thenReturn(...);
        when(details.getThing()).thenReturn(...);

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("username", "password");
        usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.setDetails(details);

        Authentication request = usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
        Authentication result = am.authenticate(request);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(result);
    }
```

#### What I tried

Noticing the above, I was going to simply create a filter.

in `web.xml` **I tried a traditional Java Servlet Filter.**

```xml
    <filter>
        <filter-name>reverseProxyAuthReceivingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.example.my.ReverseProxyAuthReceivingFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>reverseProxyAuthReceivingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

```java
public class ReverseProxyAuthReceivingFilter implements Filter {

    @Inject
    private AuthenticationManager am; // org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager

    @Inject
    private LoginUserService userService; // JPA

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
       ...
```

Unfortunately `am` is null so I can't use the same `AuthenticationManager`. So I was going to try to create the object myself from the database, but I can't get JPA dependencies to load either...

#### Let's focus.

I'm thinking if I can learn how to get `LoginUserService` (has a `@Service` annotaion on it) to be injected in a new filter that will be best.

I've searched high and low and tried some combinations of `<bean>` but am having no success so far.

How can I get a filter loaded as a `<bean>` so the `@Inject` lines will work?

Comment: Your filter isn't managed by spring so dependency injection doesn't apply. Make the filter a spring managed bean and use a `DelegatingFilterProxy` to obtain it. Or even better make it a managed bean and make it part of your security filter chain by using `addFilter` because that is where it actaully belongs.

Comment: Okay, I am going to try `addFilter` on `MySecurityConfig.java`. (having `@WebSecurity` already)

Comment: For those using `<bean>` syntax for security filter chain, perhaps this helps https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html.

Comment: relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21983048/exception-with-custom-restauthenticationprocessingfilter-ordering

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [M. Deinum's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67134599/in-production-mock-authentication-for-spring-security-from-reverse-proxy-but?noredirect=1#comment118670011_67134599) mentioning security filter chain filters, I have discovered the solution.

In `MySecurityConfig.java` (having `@EnableWebSecurity` on it)

```java
    @Inject
    ReverseProxyAuthReceivingFilter reverseProxyAuthReceivingFilter;

    ...
    http.addFilterBefore(reverseProxyAuthReceivingFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
```

(as per [Exception with (Custom) RestAuthenticationProcessingFilter Ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21983048/exception-with-custom-restauthenticationprocessingfilter-ordering/21988934#21988934), we have to use `addFilterBefore` or `addFilterAfter`)

In `applicationContext.xml`

```xml
<bean id="reverseProxyAuthReceivingFilter" class="com.example.my.ReverseProxyAuthReceivingFilter" />
```

```java
public class ReverseProxyAuthReceivingFilter implements Filter {

    // Dependency injection works when filter is Bean! Yay!
    @Inject
    private AuthenticationManager am;

    @Inject
    private LoginUserService userService;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest reqO, ServletResponse resO, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) reqO;
        if (...) {
            MyAuthenticationDetails details = new MyAuthenticationDetails(...);

            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("username", "password");
            usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.setDetails(details);

            Authentication request = usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
            Authentication result = am.authenticate(request);
...
```